# Problems od special characters with sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, widget, special-characters, dropdownchoice

I'm using sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice to get a list of languages from a MySql database. The list is in spanish language. All languages with special characters like for ex. Árabe looks OK (it got the tilde), but I'm getting the wrong representation (A!rabe) using the widget.
How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an encoding problem: verify that the list of languages registered in your database has the same encoding than the page where you display the widget.

But why don't you use the [sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage widget](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage) ?

Comment: I completely ignored the existence of this widget. Thanks a lot.